# MySQLi Query returns empty

Tags: php, json, mysqli

I'm trying to lookup values in a mysql database using keys I get from a JSON file.
Currently, this is the code:

```
<?php

$db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'colorred');
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
     die(mysqli_connect_error());
}

$data = file_get_contents('http://paulglushak.com/json/test.json');
$parse = json_decode($data,true);
$time = date('l, d-M-Y H:i:s T', $parse['id']/1000);
$title = $parse['title'];

echo '<br><br>',$time,'<br>';
echo $title,'<br>';
if(!($parse['data']==null)) {
    foreach ($parse['data'] as $code) {
        $query = "SELECT `city` FROM `city_table` WHERE (CONVERT(`code` USING utf8) LIKE '".$code."')";
        echo 'The Query: ' .$query.'<br>';
        $result = mysqli_query($db, $query) or die('Error: '.mysqli_error($db));
        echo '<hr>';
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            echo $row;
            }
        }
    mysqli_close($db);
}


?>
```

One of the queries for example is:

```
SELECT `city` FROM `city_table` WHERE (CONVERT(`code` USING utf8) LIKE 'נגב 297')
```

phpmyadmin returns results, as seen here: http://paulglushak.com/json/mysql_result.html

The PHP code however returns as empty. Is there anything I'm doing wrong? I'm pretty sure I am.

Comment: I see an Unicode character. There is a chance that the character is unable to transcode in the process. Is the echo result of query normal (same as what you expect)?

Comment: What's the point of using mysqli without prepared statements?.. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php Your code is vulnerable to MySQL injection

Comment: @VladimirHraban Incorrect concept. Not using prepared statement does not equal to vulnerable to SQL Injection (Not MYSQL injection). Properly escape the input data can avoid the injection attack. Read prepared statement documentation for more information.

Comment: @Raptor Yeah, echoing the query shows up fine.

Comment: Debug Step 2: The character shows up fine is properly because your browser helps you to do so. Try to change to plain text by adding `header("Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8");` at the first line of your PHP.

Comment: @Raptor done that, still empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end it was an encoding issue, so thanks to Raptor for giving me a direction.

I tried debugging by adding a temporary mysql entry in English, then querying it directly, which returned the value I was looking for. This meant that Hebrew letters were the ones that were causing the issue. The issue was solved by adding

```
mysqli_set_charset($db, "utf8");
```

after the connection.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably have wildcards in your like statement:

```
$query = "SELECT `city` FROM `city_table` WHERE (CONVERT(`code` USING utf8) LIKE '%".$code."%')";
```

But I would not advise making SQL queries in a loop. Better to build one query from the loop and run it once.

Comment: OP mentioned that the same query works in phpMyAdmin (PMA). Not related to wildcard.